# Accessing Context

Tags: android, android-context, locationmanager

I have a broadcast receiver used to receive a broadcast from pending intent using API `requestLocationUpdates`.
The context which I receive in the `onReceive(..)` method has all the UI elements and objects of the calling activity in it (Which I could see using the Watch Window).
Is there any way/method to access these UI elements or any objects contained within the context?

Here's a snippet:

```
MainActivity {
   //Initialize a pending intent         
   locationmanagerobject.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0,pendingintent); 
   //registering broadcast reciver
} 

broadcastReciverClass { 
   onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
       /*I want to gain access to the objects of the main Activity. I can
         see them in context if I use the watch window to monitor the 
         context object. I want to find a way to be able to access them and use them*/ 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I found a way to do it! 

Creating the broadcast reciver within the same activity reuslts in the broadcast receiving class to have access to the UI elements of the activity!!

However I would like to know if there is any way one can use the UI elements of one activity from another activity/service/Broadcast Rx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to gain access to the objects on the main activity? I'm asking because I'm wondering if there's a better architectural decision that could be made. Activities are intentionally modular.

If you're looking to update the UI components in MainActivity when receiving the broadcast, you could do the following:

- Broadcast a message from the broadcastReciverClass and register a receiver in MainActivity to update accordingly.
- Change data in a shared/singleton class when receiving a message and make the appropriate UI change in MainActivity in the onResume() method.